# anomalous behaviour in MATLAB inputParser

Tags: matlab, parsing

I'm using inputParser to validate inputs to an adaptive thresholding routine in Matlab 2016a.

The input is:

```
AdaptBinarize2(Image, 'WeightedNiblack', 'meanWeight', 0.3, 'varianceWeight', 0.5, 'meanWindow', 8, 'varianceWindow', 8);
```

Where the name-value pairs 'meanWindow', 8 and 'varianceWindow', 8 are of interest.

The inputParser is a local function in the same file as AdaptBinarize:

```
function p = parseInputs(I, algorithm, varargin)

p = inputParser;

deft = 0.5; %default t, mean weight
defs = 2*floor((size(I,1)+size(I,2))/32)+1; %default s, window size
defk = 0; %default k, variance weight
defm = 128; %default m, Sauvola variance term (max variance of uint8)
defPol = 'Bright'; %foreground polarity, 'Bright' or 'Dark'
defGPU = 'False'; %whether to use CUDA

addRequired(p, 'I', @isnumeric);
addRequired(p, 'algorithm', @ischar);

addOptional(p, 'windowSize', defs, @isint);
addOptional(p, 'meanWindow', defs, @isint); %<--- this sucks
addOptional(p, 'varianceWindow', defs, @isint);

addOptional(p, 'meanWeight', deft, @isnumeric);
addOptional(p, 'varianceWeight', defk, @isnumeric);
addOptional(p, 'magicNumber', defm, @isint);

addOptional(p, 'polarity', defPol, @ischar);
addOptional(p, 'UseGPU', defGPU, @ischar);

parse(p,I,algorithm, varargin{:})

end
```

I'm using @isint as a validation function. isint is defined as a local function in the same file as AdaptBinarize2():

```
function bool = isint(x)

epsilon = 10^-9;

if mod(x, 1) < epsilon;
    bool = true;
else
    bool = false;
end

end
```

When entering the input, I get the error message :

```
Error using AdaptBinarize2>parseInputs (line 371)
The value of 'meanWindow' is invalid. It must satisfy the function: isint.

Error in AdaptBinarize2 (line 67)
p = parseInputs(I, algorithm, varargin{:}); 
%check all the name-value pairs and datatypes. local function.
```

isint(8) = true. If I change the meanWindow check handle to @isnumeric the parsing is succesful. All the others sanity checks which use @isint pass. Including varianceWindow, which is input at the same time with the same value and still passes.

When extracting the values from the inputParser struct after changing the @isint to @isnumeric the values are the same with the same datatype.

If I switch the lines of meanWindow and varianceWindow in inputParser the exact same behaviour happens in reverse, with varianceWindow failing unless I change the test and meanWindow passing. The order of input doesn't seem to have any effect.

What is happening and why?

Comment: What are your inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `addParameter` rather than `addOptional`.

`addOptional` indicates that the argument is an *optional* argument. Optional arguments follow on from the first argument, must be in order, but later ones can be omitted and are replaced by defaults.

`addParameter` indicates that the argument is a *parameter-value pair*. Parameter-Value pair arguments can come in any order, and are passed in as a pair with the name of the argument and its value.

PS prior to R2013b, use `addParamValue` rather than `addParameter`.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, rubber ducked it. The syntax was wrong, I though that addOptional() would work like addParameter() works really. addOptional() is a positional argument, so the name string-identifier is not enough to push stuff into their right places. addParameter() can sort them with just the name like I tried to.

So instead of having a good routine that exhibits anomalous behaviour I had a broken routine that worked purely by chance. It even output images that looked like what I expected with the inputs shuffled!